# MongoDB Change Stream heavy on system resources

Tags: mongodb, server, changestream

I'm using MongoDB change stream in order to have indirect communication between servers.
One API server is in DMZ and the other is in Intranet, DB server is also in DMZ and both API servers are allowed to communicate with DB via 27017 port. 
DMZ API server is doing **inserts** to DB and is listening for **"update"** event in order to return response to user, while Intranet API server is listening for **insert** event and doing updates to those documents only. Once Intranet API updates the document, response is returned to user from DMZ API. Hope this makes sense so far.

That being a setup, I have an issue with DB server. It's complaining about swap memory being full always and since it's replica set, there are 3 servers in it and each has 4GB of RAM.
Do I need to add more RAM, and how much if anyone knows?

Comment: How big is your dataset? Is the server running on Windows?

Comment: @Oleg All servers are Linux. Since this DB is used for communication between DMZ API and Intranet server, there can be a lot of requests. All requests that get to DMZ API go in DB and from there it's "picked" by Intranet, updated and DMZ API catches update and returns response to user. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: How big is the dataset?

Comment: @Oleg There are 8k users and they all use constantly app. There can be more than 300-500k documents created in one day. Not sure if this info is of any use to you. I dont have access to this production database, so I cant see exact stats.